# How I return array of my class type object?

Tags: java, arrays, object, return

Reedited...

```
    public EventData getEventDetails(String evtId, String Status) {
    //do some data selection here.
    return evData1;
    }

    public EventData[] getAdminAuthEvtDetails(String evtId, String Status) {
    String eId=evtId;
    String status=Status;
    EventData[] evData=new EventData[2];
    EventData[0] evData=getEventDetails(eId,"V");
    EventData[1] evData=getEventDetails(eId,"M");
    return evData;
    }
```

EventData is my java data class. In there I set getters and setters. I want to call getEventDetails method two time one status as verified and other as modified for requested ID and set both evData into one array. In here there give a error couldn't get data into EventData[0] and EventData[1].Is there any error of calling my getEventDetails method?

Finally I got correct code.

```
    EventData[] evData=new EventData[2];
    evData[0]=getEventDetails(eId,"V");
    evData[1]=getEventDetails(eId,"M");
    return evData;
```

Comment: `return eData;` this type of question is easily searchable.

Comment: *Is this correct?* -> Depends on what you want to do. You haven't really told us what that method is supposed to do. You just told what it's doing. Better to explain the real problem, rather than the issue with your solution. So we can help better.

Answer (score 3):

in both methods you must return an object rather than Type

in 1st method:

```
public EventData getEventDetails(String evtId, String Status) {
    return new EventData(evtId, status);//don't know how is you constructor of EventData, but its just a smart guess. the idea is to create an object
}
```

and in 2nd method  `return eData;`

Comment: check out `getEventDetails` method.

Comment: @ay89 I have reedited my code.But I couldn't getEventDetails method data into my EventData[0] and EventData[1]. It gives error as incompatible types.Requires EventData[].

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to update your `getEventDetails` method as well. `EventData` is a `class` however you need to return an instance of the `class` generally created by calling the constructor `new EventData()`.

Otherwise, ay89 is correct that `getAdmin...` should return `eData`.

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, it's correct.  You just have some syntax issues that others have mentioned (like returning a variable instead of a class).

Otherwise, some other things to note:

- You'll want to probably use a lowercase "s" for "Status" since conventionally, variables shouldn't start with upper cases.
- You probably dont need to redeclare the evtId to eid.  You can just use the evtId (and the incorrectly cased Status) variable directly.
- Personally, I like to perhaps call the getEventDetails(...) method something more like createEventDetails(...) since it's more indicative of the function of that method.  "Get" always implies fetching instead of creating to me.

Just my 2c